# How to replan a Linux LVM+mdadm setup to boot back the right way?

Tags: lvm, grub, mdadm, system-recovery

I own a Linux setup in a couple of mdadm mirrored (RAID 1) disks with LVM2 on the top. For whatever reasons I need to replan this system/storage structure from scratch which means to copy out the whole system, wipe the whole LVM+mdadm RAID, set it up afresh and copy back the whole system, so I would do something like:

1. Boot from a live distro.
2. Copy the whole system somewhere (except */dev, /proc*, etc. by means of `mount --bind` --maybe plain `mount` would be better?--).
3. Do `parted /dev/sd<a,b> mklabel gpt` which I suppose it should destroy the existing LVM building. Then do the partitioning stuff.
4. Build the new *mdadm* stuff, then rescan *mdadm* devices into a new `/etc/mdadm.conf`.
5. Build LVM on top (PV, VG, LV), file system thing.
6. Copy data back.

Now I'm concerned about proper things to change in the old system to achieve a graceful boot into the new setup. I guess I should:

- Update `/etc/fstab` with the new UUIDs.
- `chroot` into the new system from live. Then...
- Do something to `grub.cfg`? `grub-mkconfig`?
- `grub-install /dev/sda && grub-install /dev/sdb`.
- `update-initramfs -u`.
- Anything to sort / add / remove / care of?

Comment: Your step 2 won't do what you want it to. A simple `mount` won't copy anything, and you will end up losing data with this plan. You need to actually copy data to another system and/or disk in order to preserve it.

Comment: 2) `mount  --bind` applies only if you copy files within the running system. On a Live CD, the filesystem you want to copy is not mounted to `/` anyway, so you don't have to jump hoops to avoid special submounts. That's unless you reintroduce those mounts by chrooting...

Comment: @John yes I know I must use either `rsync` or `cp` for copying, I was just wondering whether it made sense to use `mount --bind` or plain `mount` to get it right.

Comment: @frostschutz Thank you for pointing out that!